# Control zooming features of WebView content from outside of WebView, in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I want to control the **zoom in** and **zoom out** features from the outside of the `WebView` with some different buttons. Is it possible? if 'yes' how?
My target is hiding the `WebView` zoom controls and controlling the zoom in/zoom out feature manually using two **FAB** (+ and - Fab button) button which is on my android layout. 
Any kind of help will  be appreciable. Thanks

Update: Problem has been resolved. I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible? if 'yes' how?

Yes you can zoomin and zoomout webview by using your ***FAB*** button. You can check demo from git for solution of this.

https://github.com/plusinfosys-global/webviewzoom